# No items to show in Stack Exchange Android app

Tags: bug, status-completed, android-app

As depicted in the snap, initially it shows a *No items to show...* message and then after blinking of eyes, it displays the feeds/questions list.

**Issue:** if there aren't any items to show in the list then from where did it get the questions list?

> [image]

Comment: I've noticed this too. I guess it should say something like "Loading Questions..." until they are shown, then if there really are none *then* it should show "No items/questions to show"

Comment: @GeorgeDuckett exactly!!

Comment: @George but it means... writing extra line of code! ;)

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd looking forward for your great "Without code" solution :)

Comment: @PareshMayani if I had such power I would be very rich by now... :P

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd: The no-code solution would be change the wording to "No items to show... yet" Then it applies when loading and when there's nothing there. Think the code solution might be better though!

Comment: In an ideal world, the app would just store the last available list of questions locally and show them until new questions are fetched.

Comment: @Bibhas that would be also a nice solution.

Comment: I had this happen to me when viewing the boardgames site and there where questions showing until I tried to refresh the page

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The next version v0.1.10 will be a bit more sane about when to show the "no items to show..." view.

Comment: Yes i just updated app with 0.1.10 and can see this issue is fixed.